# Eclipse external dependencies for Spring Boot - why doesn't it show all dependencies for Spring boot for a given project?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependencies

I'm trying to figure out if any of our spring-boot projects use spring-cloud, which has a recently discovered exploit.

I know spring-boot comes with spring-cloud as a dependency, but when I check the project in Eclipse for external dependencies, none of them show spring-cloud as a dependency. This is good, but why?

I also saw that many projects uses a spring-boot component, spring-boot-autoconfigure, which has spring-cloud-spring-service-connector as a dependency. This also doesn't show as an external dependency, but again, why? It seems if it's listed in the component's maven as a dependency, it should automatically become an external dependency.

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't have Spring Cloud as a dependency... Spring Cloud has Spring Boot as a dependency. So your understanding is flawed.

Comment: True, I got turned around. Can you explain the second item?

Comment: What do you want explained? If Spring Boot isn't using Spring Cloud you obviously won't see those dependencies... If a project isn't using a dependency why should it show up?

Comment: Spring cloud is included in Spring boot. Spring-boot-autoconfigure, part of spring boot, has spring-cloud-spring-service-connector as a dependency. Why isn't it listed as an external dependency of the project that uses spring-boot-auto-configure?

Comment: Because Spring Cloud **isn't** a dependency of `spring-boot-autoconfigure`. Spring Cloud depends on Spring Boot **not** the other way around.

Comment: .m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.4.RELEASE>type spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.pom | findstr spring.cloud
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>

Comment: You can check all the dependencies for [`spring-boot-autoconfigure` ](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/build.gradle) and you see that there is nothing Spring Cloud related in there, just regular Spring porfolio projects.

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

Comment: The version you point to is an old one, and if you check that it is an **optional** dependency, like most of those in there. And optional dependencies are never included.

Comment: This is in the file .m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.4.RELEASE>type spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.pom

Comment: You might want to include the Spring Boot version you are concerned with (as you see it differs quite a lot between versions)!.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the optional. So it could be used by the project, but since it's optional it's not marked? I guess I don't know what optional means.

Comment: Yeah, it's old, but the vulnerability says old versions are vulnerable of curse

Comment: Thanks, your comments were extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spring-boot-autoconfigure` mainly has `optional` dependencies and those are never transitivly and automatically included in projects that use `spring-boot-autoconfigure`. How [optional dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#how-do-optional-dependencies-work) work is explained in the Maven documentation.

If you want to use those you need to explicitly mention those in your project as well, which is why you won't see them if not explicitly mentioned.